# paypal payment standard page in mobile view

Tags: mobile, paypal

In our application the paypal site is not in mobile view. it looks like web view and not fit into the mobile display . i need to know how to make mobile responsive paypal site. anyone please help me to get out of this. and we using paypal payment standards.thanks in advance.

Comment: What code currently displays Paypal on your site?

Comment: what is your site URL?